# Django - Generic View Subclassed - url Parameters

Tags: django, subclass, django-generic-views

I need to display a detail page for a video with some other data.
For that I use `DetailView` that I have overridden to add some variables to the context.

Here are the code parts:

```
#urlconf
#...
  (r'viewtube/(?P<pk>\d+)$', VideoFileDetailView.as_view()),
#...

#view
class VideoFileDetailView(DetailView):
  model = VideoFile
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VideoFileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
#    context['rates'] = VideoRate.objects.filter(video=11, user=1)
    return context
```

Here `pk` is the id of a video, I need to get the rates of the selected video by the current user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been useful to show the models. But I think you need to override `get()`, not `get_context_data`, as unfortunately the latter doesn't get passed the request, which you need in order to get the user. So:

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    context['rates'] = VideoRate.objects.filter(video=self.object, user=request.user)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: Aparently from `get_context_data()` we can get the request trought `self.request`, thanks it's working with that

Answer (score 4):

The request should be accessible at `self.request`. `self.request` is set at the beginning of the request (in `View.dispatch`) and should be available any of the subclass methods.

```
class VideoFileDetailView(DetailView):
  model = VideoFile
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VideoFileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['rates'] = VideoRate.objects.filter(video=11, self.request.user)
    # note that the object is available via self.object or kwargs.get("object")
    return context
```

Comment: I also needed to filter on the `VideoFile` itself, so with `video=self.object` I'm getting what I'm searching for.

Comment: Thanks Yuji. I haven't experimented much with class-based views, and was a bit surprised that `request` wasn't explicitly passed to `get_context_data`.

Comment: Hmm you're right! It's a little more magical than I'm used to when going through code. Well, it's brand new ;)