# Accessing Primary Key from URL in Django View Class

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I have a URL pattern mapped to a custom view class in my Django App, like so:

```
url( r'^run/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PerfRunView.as_view( ))
```

The problem is, I cannot figure out how I can access 'pk' from the URL pattern string in my view class so that I can retrieve a specific model object based on its database id. I have googled, looked through the Django documentation, searched Stack Overflow, and I can't find a satisfactory answer at all.

Can anybody tell me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427004/django-generic-view-subclassed-url-parameters does this help ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#performing-extra-work read the second note.

Comment: @Ankur Gupta Thanks for the links, but I'm still not totally clear on it. Is it part of self.kwargs? I thought I was getting the hang of Django, until I got into class-based views. I just don't understand them at all.

Comment: @luke class based view is just an abstraction I for one finds it annoying and stick to functions. I don't think they help a lot. Not necessary you need to use it. Using simple function against URLs work fine too.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In a class-based view, all of the elements from the URL are placed into `self.args` (if they're non-named groups) or `self.kwargs` (for named groups). So, for your view, you can use `self.kwargs['pk']`.

Comment: I've sorted it now. I even have a better understanding of how Django View classes work, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

to access the primary key in views
post =

```
Class_name.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example based on django restframework to retrieve an object using pk in url:

views.py

```
class ContactListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserContactListSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        contacts = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = UserContactListSerializer(contacts)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^contact_list/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ContactListView.as_view())
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have said `self.kwargs` works fine.
It particularly helps in `self.get_queryset()` function, unlike `list`, `create` where `pk` works better.