# Django - Simple custom template tag example

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have *users*, *videos*, *topics*, *criterias* and *ratings*

- A *video* has a *topic*
- A *topic* has *criterias*
- A *user* can create a *video* for a given *topic*
- A *user* can rate a *video* on each *criterias* given for the concerned *topic*.

You can see my original post [Django - Rating Model Example DetailView Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388259/django-rating-model-example-detailview-template) to get details on the model used

I have extended a `DetailView` template based on the *video* model to put the list of *ratings* for the selected *video* for a given *user* as extra context.

```
class VideoFileDetailView(DetailView):
  model = VideoFile

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VideoFileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['rates'] = VideoRate.objects.filter(video=self.object, user=self.request.user)
    return context
```

In the template pointed by the `DetailView`, I'd like to list the *criterias* of the *video*, and for each *criteria* display the current **rating value** form the *user*.

```
<div id="rating">
  <ul>
{% for crit in videofile.topic.crits.all %}
    <li>
  {% for rate in rates %}
    {% if rate.crit.id == crit.id %}
      {{ rate.rate }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
      <div class="rateit"
        data-rateit-value="{# The rating value #}"
        data-rateit-ispreset="true"
        crit-id="{{ crit.id }}"></div>
      {{ crit }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

([rateit](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm) is a jquery plugin that I use to draw pretty stars rating controls)

Actually I get my rating values here within the 2nd `for` but I'm sure there is a better way to do that. In fact, I'm still not sure about my [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388259/django-rating-model-example-detailview-template) correctness.

Finally I'd like to replace `{# The rating value #}` by the rating value from rate for the current crit (in the loop). How can I do that ?

Comment: You could simplify your template code if you add helper properties on your models that do some of this for you, for example the rate for loop.

Comment: Actually, it would probably be best as a template tag. Pass in `rates` and `crit`, return `rates.filter(crit=crit)`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Here is my solution (based on a **custom tag**):

Firstly create the file structure. Go into the app directory where the tag is needed, and add these files:

```
templatetags
templatetags/__init__.py
templatetags/video_tags.py
```

The **templatetags/video_tags.py** file:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_rate(crit, rates):
    return rates.get(crit=crit).rate
```

The template part, with our tag call:

```
{% load video_tags %}

<div id="rating">
  <ul>
{% for crit in videofile.topic.crits.all %}
    <li>
      <div class="rateit"
        data-rateit-value="{% get_rate crit rates %}"
        data-rateit-ispreset="true"
        crit-id="{{ crit.id }}"></div>
      {{ crit }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you import video_tags? {% load video_tags %}

Comment: Also.. "you will need to restart your server before you can use the tags or filters in templates." [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: and it still doesn't load it. have no clue at all what's happening

Comment: 'custom_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list ... etc

Answer (score 17):

**Inline HTML in tag**

If the HTML is small, this method is more convenient than creating a separate file.

This example factors out links to user profiles. The file `templatetags/somemodule.py` contains:

```
from django import template
from django.template import Template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def user_link(context):
    return Template('<a href="{% url \'user_detail\' ' +
            'user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a>').render(context)
```

`Template#render` already returns a safe string which is not XSS escaped. E.g. if we had done just:

```
return '<br>'
```

it would be escaped. You might also want to play with `mark_safe`.

You can make that tag available on all views with:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'OPTIONS': {
            'builtins': [
                'myprojectname.templatetags.somemodule',
```

in `settings.py`.

See also:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/
- [Rendering a template variable as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848611/rendering-a-template-variable-as-html)

Comment: Thank you, this solved a big problem of mine.