# Django Custom Template Tag not returning any value

Tags: django, django-templates

I am learning how to create and use Custom Template Tags. The [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) is great at describing how to add templatetag functionality etc but it does not say much about actually creating one.

My problem is that I'm trying to return the value of the below random url choice in my views.py file but nothing is appearing in my page.

**views.py**

The idea of this is that `survey_url` (template tag) takes a random URL value to direct the user to one of three surveys when they click on the start button..

```
def start(request):
    survey_urls = ['/surveyone/', '/surveytwo/', '/surveythree/']
    survey_url = random.choice(surveys)
    return render(request, 'start.html', {'survey_url': survey_url})
```

**.html**

This random URL is then meant to be loaded into the `href" "` in a button on start.html. I am loading the `survey_extras` and have included the template tag.

```
{% load survey_extras %} 
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{survey_url}}">START</a>
```

**Project Structure**

I have created the templatetags directory inside my application and included an `__init__.py` file
[image: project structure]

**survey_extras.py**

This is where I get a bit stuck. There does not seem to be many tutorials online (that I can find) which deal with how to code it. I have been looking at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsLg_NFAHLk) but its much more complex than I need. I have also been looking at this question [Django - Simple custom template tag example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6451304/1214163) but cant seem to get it.

```
from django import template    
register = template.Library()
from survey.views import start

@register.simpletag


def survey_url():
    return ''
```

Currently I am getting no errors and when i inspect the button element no aditional URL code is appearing.

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong? Thanks ;-)

Comment: I don't understand why you want a custom template tag here. You're sending the value straight from the view to the template: no new tags required.

Comment: Not to be rude, but why would you expect a value to be present in the template when your template tag returns an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

As @Brandon says you are doing:

```
from django import template    
register = template.Library()
from survey.views import start

@register.simpletag        
def survey_url():
    return ''
```

What do you expect to receive from the custom template tag if you're doing:

```
def survey_url():
    return ''
```

You have to create a function to "randomly" choose any of your urls. An example of a function to get a random url could be like this:

```
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver    
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import random
register = template.Library()
from survey.views import start

@register.simpletag        
def survey_url():
    # First we need to get a list of the url's
    url_list = get_resolver(None).reverse_dict.keys()
    # Then we generate random number from 0 to url_list lenght
    random_number = random.randint(0, len(url_list)-1)   
    # and then we return one value of the list
    return reverse(url_list[random_number])
```

Other option is to use urlpatterns:

```
from django import template    
register = template.Library()
from survey.views import start
import urls

@register.simpletag        
def survey_url():
    # First we need to get a list of the url's
    url_list = urls.patterns
    # Then we generate random number from 0 to url_list lenght
    random_number = random.randint(0, len(url_list)-1)   
    # and then we return one value of the list
    return url_list[0].regex.pattern
```

- The first way return the name of an url (you will need to make something like ..href="{% url survey_url %}").
- The second one return the url pattern as it is in your urls file

The problem with this kind of functions is that if you have complex urls that manage codes like:

```
u'^your_url/(?P<item_id>\\w+)?/?$'
```

the template will get errors if you don't pass the neccessary attributes to the url. Possible solution could be to have in one file the urls you want to "randomize" and the complex url's in other file.