# Django inclusion_tag contents not displaying

Tags: django, tags, django-templates, inclusion

I cannot get the contents of an inclusion_tag to display. I am not getting an errors so i know that the tag is registering and I am almost certain that it is loading correctly. The tag is created in crudapp/templatetags/crudapp_tags.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("forum.html")
def results(poll):
    form = 'blah'
    return {'form': form}
```

templates/forum.html

```
  {% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load crudapp_tags %}
{% results poll %}
<p>aaa</p>
{% block homepage %}
<p>bbb</p> <!-- Only this displays -->
{% if form %}
<p>Form exists</p>
{% endif %}
{% for item in form %}
<p>This is {{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<div>
  <p>{% if user.is_authenticated %}Add a New Topic: <a href="{% url 'topic_form' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>{% endif %}</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>{{ totalposts.count }} posts, {{ totaltopics.count }} topics, {{ totalusers.count }} users, {{ totalviews.numviews}} views</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The file set up is as follows,

[image]

Comment: Something here doesn't make sense; your inclusion tag is rendering a template that is using the tag itself.

Comment: Also the `templates` directory should be inside your app directory instead of the root of the project, unless you have explicitly told Django to look there.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what an inclusion tag does. An inclusion tag renders *another* template. Since you have `{% results poll %}` outside of a block, the result of the tag will never be displayed. Maybe you want an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) instead (In Django 1.9 you can use simple tag instead of assignment tag).

Comment: @solarissmoke So I can't use this tag to display 'blah' in any template, it must be a template in the app. That means I need to create a new template directory in my app called crudapp. At the moment I have all my templates in the project directory.

Comment: @Alasdair yes you are probably right that I don't get the concept of inclusion tags. I thought it was a way of getting context into a template without using a url. And this tag could be repeatedly used in other templates.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so should the inclusion tag be in index.html and not used in forum.html ? I can not find any example of inclusion tags which shows how to use them instead they just show how to register the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an inclusion tag, then the tag renders *another* template. You need to move the code that uses `form` out of `forum.html` and into a new template, e.g. `results.html`

results.html

```
{% if form %}
<p>Form exists</p>
{% endif %}
{% for item in form %}
<p>This is {{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then change your tag to use this template

```
@register.inclusion_tag("results.html")
def results(poll):
    form = 'blah'
    return {'form': form}
```

Finally, since you are extending a template, you need to move then tag into a block, otherwise the result won't be used.

```
{% block homepage %}
{% results poll %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

If you want to add an item to the template context instead of rendering another template, then you want a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) instead.

```
@register.simple_tag
def fetch_result():
    result = ['foo', 'bar']
    return result
```

Then in your template:

```
{% fetch_result as result %}

{% for item in result %}
<p>This is {{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The `{% fetch_result as result %}` works for simple tags in Django 1.9+. In earlier versions, you want an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags).

Comment: when you say an 'item' do you mean just one string or could that still be the result of a query, which is what I would like it to be later on. But for now I just wanted to simplify it and get 'blah' into the template.

Comment: If you are using the simple tag, the result can be any object you like. You used a string `'blah'`, I changed it to a list `['foo', 'blah']` because it makes a bit more sense to loop over a list in the template. It can be a queryset if you want.

Comment: Should the templates here be in a templates directory in the app crudapp even though I have specificied in settings.py that templates are where they are in the file set up shown in the question? settings.py looks like this,  TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],............

Comment: Using Django 1.9 by the way.

Comment: As long as Django can find your templates, I wouldn't worry too much about the template location at the moment, it's a separate question.

Comment: So crduapp_tags.py is  from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("results.html")
def results(poll):
    form = 'blah'
    return {'form': form}

Comment: and templates/results.html is not in an app template directory but in the templates directory and is  {% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load crudapp_tags %}

{% block test %}
{% if form %}
<p>Form exists</p>
{% endif %}
{% for item in form %}
<p>This is {{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

Comment: then in index.html I have put,          {% block test %}
        
        {% results poll %}
        {% endblock %}

Comment: Oh actually it is working now, thank you very much. I was tsuck on this for days. Great, thanks,

Comment: The results.html should be like in my answer. It doesn't need to load tags or extend other templates. If you use `{% block test %}`, it will only work if you have the same block in the template you are extending.

Comment: Sorry I can't vote you up I need 15 reps to do that.

Comment: Don't worry about the upvote. Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it has solved your question. It would be a good idea to go through your other questions, and accept other answers as well.