# Override Django Render Methods

Tags: django, templates, render

With the following renderer...

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...
return render(request, 'template.html', {'context':context,})
```

Is it possible to override the render classe's methods so that I can in certain circumstances interpret template tags myself for example if I find a tag consisting of a certain format such as...

```
{% url 'website' page.slug %}
```

I could point it to...

```
/theme/theme-1/page.html
```

or

```
/theme/theme-2/page.html
```

depending on extranious settings.

Answer (score 1):

The `render` method is just a shortcut for:

```
template = loader.get_template(''template.html')
context = {
    ...,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Therefore, it is not the correct place to try to change the behaviour of the url tag.

For the example you have given, it looks like the website should be a variable that holds `theme-1` or `theme-2`. You can then pass the variable to the url tag instead of the string `'website'`.

```
{% url website page.slug %}
```

If that is not possible, you could create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) `my_url` that returns the correct url depending on your settings.

Comment: Someone else will be responsible for the creation of the templates and will instincitly use {% url %} I just want to be able to load multiple websites in one program and intercept the routing when nessesary. This will be a library of themes but the code must run normally once added to an actual site.

Comment: as @alasdair pointed out, Instead of changing default behavior of render you should try custom template tags. Have a look at this SO post for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451304/django-simple-custom-template-tag-example

Comment: You could replace Django's url tag with your own tag using the [`BUILTINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) option. I don't think that's a good idea though. You could also look at [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects) instead of `render`, since it has extra hooks.