# Can I pass the data to base template ?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a base template, and every other template extends from it.
but the base.html, how can I set the data in it?

[image]

This is code snippet of base.html:

```
...
<li class="dropdown bell">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class=" fa fa-user-circle"></i>191457****@qq.com</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu nav-menu">
...
```

I want to change the `191457****@qq.com` to the passed data, it should be flexible, variable, that is take out from database. There is static html now.

I tried in every template to set it, but you know this is a lot of repetition operation, if there is a simple method, I think python will be worthy of the name.

Comment: Context processors or custom template tags. This is a frequently asked question.

Comment: Use django custom template tags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451304/django-simple-custom-template-tag-example)