# How can I register a custom filter in Django

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I want to register a simple filter in Django in order to concat two strings in a template. I found many questions about this here, but seemingly no answer solves my problem.

**settings.py**

```
'MedAbrDirk.apps.MedabrdirkConfig',
'MedAbrDirk.templatetags',
```

**MedAbrDirk/templatetags/my_tags.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def kette(arg1,arg2):
    return str(arg1) + str(arg2)
```

**MedAbrDirk/templates/MedAbrDirk/base.html**

```
 {% load my_tags %}
                <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                                                <li class="dropdown">
                                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Rechnungen<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                {{'test'|kette:'test2'}}
                                                                <li><a href="{% url app_var|kette:'eingabe' %}">Rechnung eingeben<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
```

Still, in the browser I get: "Invalid filter: 'kette'"

I have no idea what causes this. I have deleted the **pychache** folder, I have restarted my gunicorn several times.

Any advice?

Comment: And I also have an empty __init__.py in the templatetags folder.

Comment: And I used manage.py shell to test the import. There on the shell I can import kette and if I call it with two arguments, it returns correctly their concatenation.

Comment: is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451304/django-simple-custom-template-tag-example) is your question?

Comment: I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters) To register custom filter with decorators you can do either of

```py
# function name is taken as filter name
@register.filter
def kette(arg1, arg2):
    # code
```

OR

```py
# value in name argument is taken as filter name
@register.filter(name='kette')
def kette(arg1, arg2):
    # code
```

You can either add name `name` argument in `filter()` or remove the parenthesis from `filter()`

You say you have a `init.py` file. In-order for python to consider it as a package `__init__.py` file should be there in `templatetags` folder. Not `init.py`.

So, In your app folder you should see a structure like this for custom template tags:

```
MedAbrDirk/ #app folder
MedAbrDirk/templatetags/
MedAbrDirk/templatetags/__init__.py # should have double underscore on both the sides
MedAbrDirk/templatetags/my_tags.py
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my copy above. I already removed the (), but the result is the same.

Comment: @MDoe you commented that you have a `init.py` file. make sure that that file name is actually `__init__.py` and not `init.py`

Comment: @MDoe Also you dont need to add `'MedAbrDirk.templatetags',` to `INSTALLED_APPS ` in `settings.py`

Comment: Yes, I have a __init__.py file in the folder templatetags. Just shortened that above.

Comment: The two lines from the first code snippet are from the INSTALLED_APPS list in the settings.py

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help. It seems I figured it out by accident. In another app I also had a folder templatetags with a file my_tags.py. I thought these would be separately handled by Django. Obviously this is not the case.

So, after renaming the module, now it works.