# How do use a custom tag inside an if tag django?

Tags: python, html, django-templates

how do  use a custom tag inside an if tag?

```
ex:  {% if {%customTag  x y z %} == "Success" %}
        ...
```

my custom_field_tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def customTag(x,y,z):
    r=x+y+z
    if r ==3:
       return "Success"
    else:
       return "Wrong"
```

Comment: This link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451304/django-simple-custom-template-tag-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to slightly change your logic using Boolean values.
For you custom_field_tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def customTag(x,y,z):
    r=x+y+z
    if r==3:
        return True 
    return False
```

Then inside your html template, simply use it this way:

```
{% customTag 1 0 2 as success_result %}
                        {% if success_result %}
                        <p>it is 3</p>
                        {% endif %}
```

Comment: I understood, that was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Check this two links:
1.[django filter and tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/)

2.For custom template tags and filters:
[custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)

I think you need to see django 'Filters', according to your problem.
you will find about every kind of filter needed, if not, it is very easy to write
a custom one.