# Querying model field data in template/views without get_object_or_404()

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Homefeed is the page where i query all the blogposts

In this project, any user that sees a blogpost that they are interest in can submit their interest to the post. 1 user can only submit 1 interest to that blogpost, but they can submit as many interest as they want to different blogposts.

Right now in my home.html, I am trying to make it such that if YOU have submitted interest,(aka your interest status is at pending or accept or decline) for that particular blog post, you will see the view interest button instead of the submit interest button.

But I am facing a problem because in my views, I am querying for `blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()` and not `blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)`. As such, how am I able to query whether or not for the particular blogpost, the user has already submitted an interest in my template to determine which button should show in my home.html? Thanks, and also I dont want to change the url at all :)

views.py

```
def home_feed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts 
    page = pageFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude(author_id=request.user.id).order_by('date_updated')) 
    context['page'] = page
    paginated_page = Paginator(page.qs, 4)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginated_page.get_page(page)

    context['page_obj'] = page_obj
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)
```

home.html

```
{% for post in page_obj %}

{% if post.interest_set.exists and request.user.is_authenticated %}

     <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url 'HomeFeed:submitinterest' post.slug %}">View Interest</a>
     {% else %}  
      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'HomeFeed:submitinterest' post.slug %}">Submit Interest</a>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
path('', home_feed_view , name= "main"),
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

class Interest(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class InterestInvite(models.Model):

   ACCEPT = "ACCEPT"
   DECLINE = "DECLINE"
   PENDING = "PENDING"
   STATUS_CHOICES = [
      (ACCEPT, "accept"),
      (DECLINE, "decline"),
      (PENDING, "pending"),

   ]

   interest = models.OneToOneField(Interest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interest_invite")   
   status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)
   objects= models.Manager
```

views.py

```
        type = TypeFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude((Q(author_id__in=request.user.blocked_users.all()) | Q(author = request.user))).order_by('date_updated')).annotate(user_has_interest=Case(When(interest__user=request.user, then=Value(True)), default=False, output_field=BooleanField()))
```

Using Django filters:
filters.py

```
class TypeofIdeaFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="title", lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate a field on your query:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField

blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all().annotate(
    user_has_interest=Case(When(interest__user=request.user, then=Value(True)), default=False, output_field=BooleanField())
)
```

Now you can check in your template using if-else:

```
{% if post.user_has_interest %}
    Something
{% else %}
    Something else
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi bro, let me make it more challenging, what if I am using a filter? then I wont be able to use annotate @AbdulAzizBarkat (I have edited my code below for you to take a look..because using annotate will give me an attribute error

Comment: @hoehoehoe Simply override the qs property of the Filterset and annotate there [Filtering the primary - Django Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs)

Comment: thank you man! sorry do you mind updating the code just in case I misunderstand the documentation :)

Comment: @hoehoehoe That's a different question from the original, hence it is not correct to answer it here. Please look at [Update a question or post a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106249/update-a-question-or-post-a-new-question)

Answer (score 1):

[As Pierre mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493001/11282077) template tags also achieve this ([alternate for annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65915035/11282077) answerd by Abdul).

Firstly create the file structure. Go into the app directory where the tag is needed, and add these files:

```
templatetags
templatetags/__init__.py
templatetags/blog_tags.py
```

The **templatetags/blog_tags.py** file:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def interest_submitted(blog_id, user_id):
    if Interest.objects.filter(blog_post__id=blog_id, user_id=user_id).exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

In the template:

```
{% load blog_tags %} <!--don't forget to load the blog_tags.py file in the template. -->

{% for post in page_obj %}
{% interest_submitted post.id request.user.id as result %}
{% if result and request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url 'HomeFeed:submitinterest' post.slug %}">View Interest</a>
{% else %}  
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'HomeFeed:submitinterest' post.slug %}">Submit Interest</a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try instead of get_object_or_404(). That way you can use different logic and return different contexts if the object does not exist

pseudocode:

```
context = {}
    try:
       blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
       ...
       context = "Something"
       return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)
    
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
       context = "Something else"
       return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)
```